# What's the probability of getting at least one blue marble between my two draws?

Tags: probability

So if I have a bag with $5 $marbles in it with different colors.  Red, orange, purple, blue and green.  I draw a marble, put it back and then draw again.  What's the probability of getting at least one blue marble between my two draws?

Comment: Where are you having trouble with this?  Please show what you have tried, or at least think you should do.

Comment: If there are only two draws there can be nothing in between.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probability of getting no blue in two draws is $(\frac{4}{5})^2$ so getting at least one blue has $P=1-(\frac{4}{5})^2=\frac{9}{25}$.